# How to enable CORS for a local file that references a hosted ASP.NET Web API that is hosted on Amazon AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-2.0

So when I open a file that references a hosted `ASP.NET Web API 2.0` project, I get the error:

**Possible cross-origin (CORS) issue? The URL origin (https://secreturl.amazonaws.com) does not match the page (file://). Check the server returns the correct 'Access-Control-Allow-*' headers.**

I only get answers for enabling cores for an HTTP request pipeline but not for  (`file://`). I open the file from an `index.html` file, with path `file:///C:/Users/PCName/desktop/index.html` I assume the CORS have to be enabled in the `Startup.cs` file in the `ASP.NET Core Web API 2.0`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most browser implementations by default do not support CORS headers for local files (specifically they set the value to `null` which cannot then be used in an `Access-Control-Allow` header.)

The easiest thing to do is start a small server. If you've got Python installed, this is as easy as running `python3 -m http.server 8000` in the `C:/Users/PCName/desktop` directory, and then you can browse to `localhost:8000` (there are other 'instant servers' out there!).

That way you can use `Access-Control-Allow-*`.

Comment: Why'd you use port 8000?

Comment: There's nothing special about 8000; just one of the common ports people use for local servers- 8080, 8888 and 9000 are ones I've also seen people use. That said, anything below 1024 is "well known" and often requires system permissions to open to discourage unauthorised software impersonating things like SSH and SQL.

Comment: I was able to set the origin to null. Is there a security issue with doing that for local development?

Comment: Nvm answered my own question https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin